# Is this void* hack bad?

Tags: c++

In a header I defined a class function like this:

```
struct SDL_Window; // Forward declaration

struct SomeClass
{
     void createVulkanSurface(SDL_Window* SDL_window, VkInstance vkInstance, VkSurfaceKHR vkSurface);
};
```

So the compiler doesn't know what VkInstance and VkSurfaceKHR are. They are typedefs defined by a macro. They may be typed pointer, or a uint64_t, it's just a handle. I think the only safe thing (instead of forward declaring these and risking the types changing) is to include the vulkan.h header that defines these typedefs, but I don't want to do that because it's a big header and it'll also be included in anything I include my .h header in. I had the idea changing the function signature to:

```
void createVulkanSurface(SDL_Window* SDL_window, void* vkInstance, void* vkSurface);
```

And then in the .cpp where I define this function to cast back to VkInstance and VkSurface. I know this is safe as void* pointers can be converted to and from any pointer type. In the case the typedef is of a uint64_t then a cast to void* and back may narrow the value as a pointer is a signed integral type underlying it, isn't it?

Edit: I just thought, might it be better to take the arguments as uint64_t maybe?

Comment: They're typedeffed, VkInstance is typedeffed as typedef VkInstance_T* VkInstance; but it's under a macro , itmay change to a uint64_t. Accepting it by reference I still have a problem if the types change?

Comment: You don't want to convert pointers to non-pointer types and back. That way lies madness (and lots of undefined behavior).

Comment: @EOF MAdness hey? You can't convert from a pointer type to an integer? Why's that undefined? Can you suggest something? I really don't want to include this header. The compilation times are obscene already.

Comment: You technically *can*, but a) the rules are nontrivial (C++17 draft standard N4659: 6.7.4.3 Safely-derived pointers), and b) perhaps more importantly, I would not trust that *everybody* who may end up using any of this code will know those rules.

Comment: better would be to accept `uint64_t` and cast to `void*` than vice versa. [A pointer cast to a sufficiently large integer can be recovered by casting back](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#5). No such guarantee exists for the other way (integer cast to void* may not be recoverable).

Comment: If you’re having compilation time issues related to including too many header files (and I’ll bet you aren’t), precompiled  headers are a better solution than trying to hack away the type system.

Comment: If every file that uses your header will also use Vulcan.h then including Vulcan.h in your file won’t affect compile times. That’s what include guards do.

Comment: @PeteBecker When I include a header in another header I'm including an EXTRA header in .cpp files that ordinarily wouldn't be included (unless they were included already).

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using anything but the declaration provided by the Vulkan header. Casting between pointers and integers is risky and error prone at best, and is definitely not a recommended way of solving something. Especially if it's a macro (it could be anything, even an expression). There are ways to minimize the impact of having to include a large header that would pollute the project.

If you create a "renderer" abstraction and keep the Vulcan header included in source files (single translation unit per include) or headers that are only used in the implementation of the renderer you limit its inclusion to only the translation units where it's necessary.

Comment: I'd like to abstract a renderer class as you say, which is what I'm doing, except to initialise Vulkan I need to call the window manager (in my case SDL) to find what are the required instance extensions and have to either include the SDL headers in my vulkan stuff or include my vulkan stuff in my SDL stuff. I don't know if there's a better way to than to include stuff like this.

Comment: Including SDL stuff in the renderer seems fine as it's a legitimate dependency. You could also, if possible, pass in the available extensions that are queried from SDL outside of the renderer.